# What is this singular distribution $T(\phi)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\phi(y)}{|x-y|^n} \mathrm{d}y$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, distribution-theory, singular-integrals

I want to study the behavior of this singular distribution $T \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, defined by

\begin{equation}
T(\phi)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\phi(y)}{|x-y|^n} \mathrm{d}y, \tag{1}
\end{equation}

with $\phi(x) \geq 0$, $\phi \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I want to know if $T$ has a name, classified under what type of distributions, and its properties.

There are similar distributions. Namely if the denominator of the kernel was $(x-y)^n$ instead of $|x-y|^n$, then $T$ was just **Riesz transform** (**Hilbert transform** if $n=1$), and the integral can have a finite *principal value*.

In more general setting, if the kernel of the distribution $T(\phi)(x) = \int K_{\Omega}(x,y) \phi(y) \mathrm{d}y$ is of the form

\begin{equation}
K_{\Omega}(x) = \frac{\Omega(x/|x|)}{|x|^n}
\end{equation}

with the condition that $\Omega$ is *zero mean value* on unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, then this is **Calderon-Zygmund** kernel, and I can relate the Calderon-Zygmund decomposition ([Grafakos, section 5.2.1](https://books.google.com/books?id=94FxBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=grafakos%20third%20edition&pg=PA333#v=onepage&q=grafakos%20third%20edition&f=false)).

But the distribution of (1) is non of the above forms. becasue, its kernel $K_{\Omega}(x) = 1/|x|^n$ and $\Omega(x/|x|) =1 $ is not zero mean. I am wondering what are the name of such distributions, can they be studied by Calderon-Zygmund, or so they have their own properties? For instance, unless $\phi(0) = 0$, $T$ is always unbounded.

I am also looking for some reference suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a distribution on $\Bbb{R}^n$ because $$ \lim_{r \to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi(x)\frac{1_{|x|> r}}{|x|^n} d^n x $$ diverges whenever $\phi(0) \ne 0$. What is a (tempered) distribution is $$<T,\phi>= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (\phi(x)-\phi(0) 1_{|x|<1})\frac{1}{|x|^n} d^n x $$ 
And $$T \ast \phi(y)= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (\phi(y-x)-\phi(y) 1_{|x|<1})\frac{1}{|x|^n} d^n x $$ 
The choice of $1_{|x|<1}$ is non-canonical but you can call it $$T=fp(\frac1{|x|^n})$$ (finite part) everyone will understand that you meant $$<fp(\frac1{|x|^n}),\phi>= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (\phi(x)-\phi(0) \psi(x))\frac{1}{|x|^n} d^n x=<T+c\delta ,\phi>$$ for some $\psi(0) = 1$

Comment: Thanks for your response @reuns. In the last equation, is $\psi$ a typo? I am not sure where is came from. Also, to _regularize_ $|x|^{-n}$, should not you need more terms to subtract besides $\phi(0)$? Something like $\phi(x) - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i!}x^i \phi^{(i)}(0)$? I guess your answer is correct for $n=1$ only.

Comment: (from the volume of the $n$-dimensional annulus) we find $|x|^{-a}$ is $L^1_{loc}$ iff $a<n$ so $\phi(0)=0 \implies \phi(x) = O(|x|)\implies |x|^{-n}\phi(x)\in L^1_{loc}$. Then $\psi$ is any fixed integrable function continuous at $0$ with $\psi(0)=1$, its choice will imply $c$.

Comment: I see, so $\psi$ represents the non-uniqueness of regularization. On second question, what if say $n=1$ and $a > 1$ for distribution $|x|^{-a}$? I guess we need those extra terms. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Yes $<fp(|x|^{-n-1}),\phi>= \int_{\Bbb{R}^n} |x|^{-n-1} (\phi(x)-(\phi(0)+\sum_{j=1}^n x_j \partial_{x_j} \phi(0)) 1_{|x|<1} )d^n x$ and so on

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, unless $\phi(x) = 0$ this distribution isn't really a distribution since distributions need to be continuous linear functionals. But we can modify it by taking the action $$T_x(\phi) = \text{p.v.}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\phi(y)-\phi(x)}{|x-y|^n}dy$$ which we can consider as a family of distributions that are shifted by x from $$T_0(\phi) = \text{p.v.}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\phi(y)-\phi(0)}{|y|^n}dy$$ $T_0$ has some special properties, namely it is a homogeneous radial distribution of degree $-n$. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ another radial distribution with that homogeneity is the Dirac delta $\delta_0$ in $n$ dimensions. In some sense, $T_0$ can tell you what is happening with the test function everywhere except $0$, but $\delta_0$ can only tell you what is happening at $0$. In fact, any radial distribution with homogeneity $-n$ has to be some linear combination of $T_0$ and $\delta_0$

Comment: $T_0$ is better than the definition proposed by the OP but it is still not a distribution because the integral diverges for $y$ large. The correct definition is the one in reuns' answer. A consequence is that $T_0$ is not homogeneous of degree $-n$ if seen as a distribution on the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is only homogeneous if restricted to $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$. The only radial distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is homogeneous of degree $-n$ is $\delta_0$. $T_0$ is what is called an associated homogeneous distribution.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, can you please provide me some references on the _associated_ homogeneous distribution? Thanks.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam How does it diverge for large $y$ if $\phi$ is compactly supported? And I probably should have made the implied principal value explicit  given that the kernel is not locally integrable in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so I will fix that.

Comment: @Sia: a reference is the book "Generalized functions" Vol 1 by Gelfand and Shilov. The basic idea is as follows. Let $S_{\lambda}$ be the linear operator of rescaling of a distribution $T$ by a factor $\lambda$. Namely, $S_{\lambda}(T)$ is the distribution "$T(\lambda x)$" instead of "$T(x)$". $T$ is homogeneous with exponent $\alpha$ if for all $\lambda>0$, $T$ is an eigenvector of $S_{\lambda}$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda^{\alpha}$. The more general notion of associated homogeneous distribution involves replacing "eigenvector" by "generalized eigenvector" in the sense of Jordan reduction.

Comment: @NinadMunshi: What diverges is the integral over $y$ of $\phi(0)/|y|^n$. You only need it near zero and the artificial problem occurs because you integrated this term over the whole space. The solution is to do what reuns did, integrate this term over a finite ball around the origin.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Sorry about seeming obtuse, I see your point! You are absolutely right.